# How to return object datatype from python Chaquopy to android studio?

Tags: python, android, recommendation-engine, chaquopy

Hi I'm using python Chaquopy in my android studio project in order to build simple content based recommendation system. I have function which should return 5 list of movie that can be recommended to the user. But the problem is when I return the result from python to android studio, only one movie is shown.

Here is the python code [basically I refer this code from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlQZepYEppQ&list=LL&index=7)

```
def get_recomendations(title, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):

 idx = indices[title]

 sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
 sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
 sim_scores = sim_scores[1:5]
 movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
 recommendation = df2['title_x'].iloc[movie_indices]
 return  recommendation
```

Here is the Java code in Android Studio:

```
        if(!Python.isStarted()){
        Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
    }
    Python py= Python.getInstance();
    final Python pyobj = Python.getInstance();

    bttn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          PyObject pyo = pyobj.getModule("main");
          PyObject obj = pyo.callAttr("get_recomendations",IN1.getText().toString());
            textView.setText(obj.toString());

        }
    });
```

[Here the image of the apps which I insert the name of the movie then the app should show 5 Movie recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krXLt.png)

Comment: To find the source of the problem, try adding some `print` statements in your Python code to see the values of each variable. The output can be viewed in the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).

Comment: thanks sir, I found out that when I'm inserting Batman on the apps only one recommendation will shown but when I insert the dark knight rises ,5 recommendation is shown.